# Best strategy to share a custom dictionary in a Windows Phone 8+ app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I have the need to share across my Windows Phone 8+ app a Dictionary of custom objects.
The Dictionary is created on the startup after a call to a Rest webservice, it won't be updated, it has to be data-bound on a certain page, and interrogated from others.

I thought about instantiating a singleton class containing the Dictionary or directly the Dictionary on the App.xaml.cs.

Are there strategies that are more efficient / more practical?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [Singleton Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457788/c-sharp-singleton-pattern) would be best for your situation.

```
public sealed class MyDictionary<TKey,TValue>
{
    private static volatile Dictionary<TKey, TValue> instance;
    private static object syncRoot = new object();
    public static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (syncRoot)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
                }
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

and then you would use it in your code like:

```
        MyDictionary<string, int>.Instance.Add("one", 1);
```

Be aware that if you get sloppy with your calls, you can (and will) create multiple dictionaries:

```
        MyDictionary<string, int>.Instance.Add("one", 1);
        MyDictionary<string, string>.Instance.Add("one", "apple");
        Console.WriteLine(MyDictionary<string, int>.Instance["one"]);
        Console.WriteLine(MyDictionary<string, string>.Instance["one"]);
```

produces:

```
1
apple
```

because the second add (and second writeline) is to a different dictionary than the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution if you are using MVVM.
Create a Service Class with a property that returns your dictionary.
The class also has a method Initialize ( or DownloadData ) to fill up the dictionary, call that on app start.

Than use an IOC ( with MVVM Light you'll have SimpleIOC ), to define your instance of the Service class, most IOC's will always return the 'one' instantiated version, in other words singleton.